# fit theoretical distribution and draw random values

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

In order to fit given data to theoretical distribution and then draw random values from that distribution, does this scheme work with all distributions in `scipy.stats`?

```
from scipy.stats import beta, expon, gamma, genpareto, genextreme, lognorm, kappa3, pearson3, weibull_min

data = [529, 7065, 2739, 1838, 817, 1376, 3791, 5070,
        736, 805, 577, 2963, 7017, 3026, 2542, 2160,
        221, 3340, 582, 1080, 1040, 1310, 5500, 4800,
        485, 7110, 4150, 2700, 4610, 1270, 10476, 1975,
        731, 150, 1163, 985, 5476, 5762, 1750, 609, 1009,
        14704, 678, 3837, 1069, 948, 460, 1819, 5958,
        1356, 2025, 1136, 4500, 882, 8230, 3521, 1561,
        695, 3380, 1210, 4311]

d = {"beta": beta,
     "expon": expon,
     "gamma": gamma,
     "genpareto": genpareto,
     "genextreme": genextreme,
     "lognorm": lognorm,
     "kappa3": kappa3,
     "pearson3": pearson3,
     "weibull_min": weibull_min} # there could be more later

ans = {}
for nm, f in d.items():
    params = f.fit(data)
    ans[nm] = f.rvs(*params, size=100)
```

I am mainly concerned about the `ans[nm] = f.rvs(*params, size=100)` line. Does `*params` always insert appropriate arguments into the `rvs` method? Or is it necessary to tinker with input based on distribution? For example, in case of `pearson3`, is it necessary to separately calculate `skew`?

Answer (score 3):

> `f.rvs(*params, size=100)` line. Does `*params` always insert appropriate arguments into the rvs method?

Yes.

f.fit returns a tuple of `shapes, loc, scale`, which can be unpacked into all other methods of `f`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as ev-br mentioned *params will insert the appropriate arguments into the rvs method.

From scipy's documentation for [scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit):
Returns a tuple of estimates for any shape parameters (if applicable), followed by those for location and scale.
Shape parameters, location, and scale can be unpacked from the `params` in your code

These estimates for shape parameters are then used by [scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

unpacking tuples work even for empty ones flawlessly.

simple test:

```py
def foo():
   print('foo')

empty=()   # empty tuple
```

```
>>> foo(*empty)
foo
```

```py
def bar(*args):
    print(args)

something = (1, 2, 3,)
```

```
>>> bar(*something)
(1,2,3)
>>> bar(*empty)
()
```

```py
def baz(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
```

```
>>> baz(*something, key='value')
(1,2,3)
{'key': 'value'}
```

So, all even `norm` distribution which does not have any specific shape parameters would work with the code you provide `rvs(*fit(data))`